# Is there a URL for pytz zoneinfo for gae?

Tags: google-app-engine, hyperlink, pytz, zoneinfo

Is there a URL link available containing the zone names like in the file zoneinfo.zip distributed with pytz.gae?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The source for the module](http://code.google.com/p/gae-pytz/source/browse/pytz/__init__.py) has them, will that do?

Comment: No, I want a (hyper)link to add to a webpage.

Comment: I found the following link, but I worry that it is not going to be there forever and would have preferred a link provided by gae or pytz. www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/unix_timestamp_to_datetime/timezones.txt

Comment: Actually, now I used your answer, also, but I am still looking for a "dependable" URL.